# display alert message ,if unable to reach the server(url)

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

how to display alert message , if i am unable to do handshake with the url ,
i am passing a URL IN THE fields below , if i am unable to meet the url (404 gatway error for url ). i need to diplay an alert box

**forget going into onpost excute,it would be stuck in do in background only but how to show alert in do in background
-**
my code

```
private class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // set message of the dialog
            asyncDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            // show dialog
            asyncDialog.setCancelable(false);
            asyncDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


            try {

                userna = user.getText().toString();
                passwd = pass.getText().toString();

                String serial = Build.SERIAL;
                Log.e("login method", userna + " " + passwd + "" + serial);
                ;
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                PropertyInfo propInfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
                propInfo1.setName("conidential");
                propInfo1.setValue(user.getText().toString().trim());
                propInfo1.setType(String.class);
                request.addProperty(propInfo1);

                PropertyInfo propInfo2 = new PropertyInfo();
                propInfo2.setName("conidential");
                propInfo2.setValue(pass.getText().toString().trim());
                propInfo2.setType(String.class);
                request.addProperty(propInfo2);

                PropertyInfo propInfo3 = new PropertyInfo();
                propInfo3.setName("DeviceId");
                propInfo3.setValue(serial);
                propInfo3.setType(String.class);
                request.addProperty(propInfo3);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                // Object response = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

                // SoapPrimitive response =
                // (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

                String status = response.getProperty("Status").toString();

                if (status.equals("1")) {

                    storename = response.getProperty("StoreName").toString();
                }

                Log.i("myApp", status.toString() + "Storename:" + storename);
                typeStatus = status.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("exception at doin", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
                @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // hide the dialog
            asyncDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                if (typeStatus.equals("1")) {
                ///////////doing my stuff
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: post the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try put into runOnUIthread into doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

```
try {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```